# Node.js security - cross-origin access?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, heroku

I'm working on a fairly simple Node server, but I am in need of some guidance on how to prevent access from undesirable origins.

My server serves two pages - the names of the pages appear in the third block of code.

Both pages connect to a Mongo database.

To test script injections, I'm using the following code and launching it locally from a simple .html file:

```
quizxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://cryptic-sierra-4333.herokuapp.com/putQuizData';
quizxhr.open("POST", url, true);
quizxhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
quizxhr.onreadystatechange = createMarkers();
quizxhr.send(quizItemToSend);
```

and

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://cryptic-sierra-4333.herokuapp.com/putHackedData';
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = displayHackedData
xhr.send(itemToSend);
```

Attempting to prevent other origins from accessing the database, I tried using this line:

```
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://cryptic-sierra-4333.herokuapp.com/", "https://cryptic-sierra-4333.herokuapp.com/admin");
```

This did not prevent my local file from accessing the database.

I have spent some time researching possible solutions, but nothing struck me as an obvious solution. Perhaps I'm not understanding my problem very well, or I may be missing some key vocabulary.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Local files will probably originate from the same network. Which network do the local files originate from? Have you tested this from a non-network location and/or had your local request spoof a foreign origin request? CORS is for stopping foreign network requests (or allowing them).

Comment: The Access-Control headers will only prevent you from sending requests that you otherwise wouldn't be able to send via a standard HTML form. In this case you're making a POST request with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. This is easily done with a normal HTML form and therefore will not be prevented by the browser. If you change the HTTP method to "PUT" or change the content type to `application/json` you should see the requests being prevented by the browser.

Comment: @Shilly My application is running on Heroku, and I'm running the hack .html file locally. After running the local hack, refreshing on Heroku shows new database entries. I believe this is adequately testing a foreign origin request, no?

Comment: @idbehold Can you help me with the syntax on how the content-type should be written (using application/json) in the server.js file?

Currently I have: res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following middleware to your NodeJS/Express app (I have added some comments for your convenience):

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://cryptic-sierra-4333.herokuapp.com/", "https://cryptic-sierra-4333.herokuapp.com/admin');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for this template, however I already had this code implemented in my server.js file (with the exception of the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials line). Unfortunately, this alone didn't solve my problem. Am I missing a detail?